# chrome.system is undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

In the chrome app, 
I want to use `chrome.system.display.getInfo` to get the resolution of the display.

However, it always reports error

> chrome.system is undefined.

Have I missed any permissions in the manifest to use chrome.system?

BTW: My chrome version is 47.0.

Comment: Nothing special. Why is the content of my background js related to it? In the console, it reports error chrome.display is undefined whether I use it in the background js or page js.

Answer (score 4):

`chrome.system.display` requires `"system.display"` [permission](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display)

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful.

Comment: and that its only available on ChromeOS.